# How to check status service on remote server Ubuntu using python?

Tags: python

I have couple servers with services on Ubuntu 22.04

1. Local server addresses = [`*.*.*.*`, `*.*.*.*`, `*.*.*.*`]
2. Services name = [`my_service1.service`,`my_service2.service`,`my_service3.service`]

How to check services status from python on one of servers? All servers are connected to a local network with each other.

Comment: Presumably by SSHing into each machine and running `systemctl status` for the services.

Comment: @AKX i thought so too, but the machines are connected to each other simply by address. they are located on the local network (database on one of the servers)

Comment: "connected to each other simply by address" doesn't really mean anything I can think of.

Comment: @AKX sorry, I just started learning this. I meant that I created a database on one server and connect to it from each server simply via IP, not via ssh. As I understand it, connection is possible without ssh

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to a remote server and get the service status value. Next, you need to find the line Active: and find out what the status of the service is.

```
import os
stream = os.system("sshpass -p '********' ssh root@*.*.*.*  'sudo systemctl status my_service'")
print(stream)
```

Comment: Well, you're using `ssh` there.

Comment: @AKX i couldn't find an example without it) i thought that servers on the local network could connect to each other without ssh

Comment: No, it's not just servers talking to each other, it's programs (such as `ssh`) running on the servers talking to each other.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you’re trying to connect to a database on a server from other servers in your local network. In Python, you can use libraries like `psycopg2` for PostgreSQL, `mysql-connector-python` for MySQL, or `pyodbc` for SQL Server to connect to your database.

If you’re using MySQL, here’s a basic example of mysql-connector-python library:

```
import mysql.connector

def check_database(server_ips, db_name, user, password):
    status_dict = {}
    for server_ip in server_ips:
        try:
            conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=server_ip,
                database=db_name,
                user=user,
                password=password
            )

            cursor = conn.cursor()

            # Execute a query
            cursor.execute('SELECT VERSION()')

            # Fetch result
            db_version = cursor.fetchone()

            # Close communication with the server
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

            status_dict[server_ip] = db_version
        except Exception as e:
            status_dict[server_ip] = str(e)

    return status_dict

# Example usage:
server_ips = ['your_server_ip1', 'your_server_ip2', 'your_server_ip3']
db_name = 'your_db_name'
user = 'your_username'
password = 'your_password'
print(check_database(server_ips, db_name, user, password))
```

I'm assuming that your database server allows connections from your client servers and that the username and password provided have the necessary permissions to execute queries.

Comment: Sorry, but I gave an example with a database in order to show that servers can connect to each other without ssh